# Create count() query from existing query

Tags: mysql, count, jooq

**edit:** I use version 1.6.8 of jOOQ; in newer versions this should work (see answer)

I am writing a gridmodel for my java web application using `Jooq` to handle the fetching of data with paging, sorting, ...

First I create a select with `factory.select(...)` and pass this (`SelectConditionStep`) as a parameter to my gridmodel where I add the needed `.limit()` and `.orderBy()` based on parameters.

But my problem now is that I also need to know the total count of results (not just 1 page) to calculate the total of pages. So my question is if it's possible in some way to create a count query from the given `SelectConditionStep`.

I thought of wrapping this as a subquery in a count query; something like:

(does not work, just to show the idea)

```java
factory.select(count()).from(selectConditionStep)...
```

**in MySQL I would do this:**

```sql
select count(*) from (select ...) as r
```

**Current code I have:**

```java
        private final SelectConditionStep selectStep;
        ...

        @Override
        public int getAvailableRows() {

            JooqSelect select = new JooqSelect() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                protected Result<Record> select(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                    Factory create = new Factory(connection, dialect);              
                    create.attach(selectStep);

                    /* This does not compile, just to show what I need */               
                    return create.select(count()).from(selectConditionStep).fetch();
                }
            };

            session.doWork(select); 

            /* Get result */
            return select.getResult()...;
        }
```

Comment: What you're trying to do should work. The [`SelectFromStep.from(TableLike...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectFromStep.html#from%28org.jooq.TableLike...%29) method accepts subselects (i.e. [`SelectConditionStep`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectConditionStep.html), which extends `TableLike`. can you provide the complete example and the error you're getting?

Comment: @LukasEder I've added some of my code. I'm pretty new with Jooq, but because of some limitations with Hibernate I'm trying Jooq, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated example mentions that `count()` is unknown. This is in fact [`DSL.count()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count()). You have three options:

- Use [`selectCount()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#selectCount()) instead of `select(count())`. That is a convenience method
- Fully qualify the [`DSL.count()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#count()) function
- Static import all methods from Factory:

  ```java
  import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
  ```

#### Referencing the `XYZStep` types:

As a side note, you should never feel the need to reference the jOOQ `XYZStep` types directly, which are used only as auxiliary types to implement the internal DSL. [Here's a blog post explaining what the alternatives are](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/06/create-empty-optional-sql-clauses-with-jooq/).

Comment: Thanks. I notice now  that the version of jOOQ being used is 1.6.8. I myself cannot change this myself (means other applications need updates too). In this version the count() method is not static and no selectCount() exists. Does this mean I'm stuck at the moment until my company decides to upgrade?

Comment: No, at the time, you had to write `create.count()`, invoking it dynamically. But I do suggest upgrading. There had been lots of improvements and bugfixes since then (October 2011)

Comment: Ok thanks, it works. Appreciate the great help :) Surely will discuss an upgrade with my colleagues